# I just started a job with Scrum and something seems to be missing. I am new to Scrum

Tags: scrum, maintenance

The code is a complete mess of a combination of classic ASP/ASP.NET. The scrum consist of us patching up the big mess or making additions to it. We are all too busy doing that to start a rewrite so I am wondering..

Where is the part in Scrum where the developers can have the power to say that enough is enough and demand that they are given time to start the big rewrite? We seem in an endless loop of just patching old code with 'Stories'.

So things are being run by the non-technical people who seem to have no desire to push for a rewrite because they don't understand how bad the codebase has gotten..

So who is in charge of making this big rewrite change happen? The developers? The Scrum Master?

The current strategy is just to find time and do it ourselves without the higher-ups involved since they are mostly to blame for the current mess we are in.. `<-` insert rant about non-technical people telling technical people what to do here `->`.

Comment: Sham agile raises its ugly head again... Many companies say they are "agile" and use "scrum", when in fact they do neither.

Comment: tell a 'story' that a rewrite is better

Comment: You are not doing Scrum

Comment: consider printing a large poster of this and placing it on the wall right where your _non-technical people_ can clearly see it: **[Manifesto for Half-Arsed Agile Software Development](http://www.halfarsedagilemanifesto.org/)** _...while the items on the left sound nice
in theory, we’re an enterprise company, and there’s no way we’re letting go of the items on the right_

Comment: Now I am only at this job 3 weeks and do not know alot about scrum yet. I just have been following what they do. MAnagment seems obsessed with scrum.. All I hear about is stories so maybe they are doing something wrong.. I need to investigate what you guys are saying.

Comment: @gnat You just made my day!  :-D

Comment: How does the symptoms of the poor code quality appear? Is development slow? Do you have problems with quality?

Comment: obligatory link to Joel's blog : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: Joel's case assumes the same devs who wrote the bad code are making the case for a total rewrite.

Comment: @Erik: No, it does not.  Almost always it is an entirely new set of devs demanding a total rewrite, and almost always that is a bad idea.

Comment: The easiest way to push for changes is to find ways that the user is being inconvenienced. If you can show "page X doesn't work", "math on page Y is incorrect", "page Z times out", then it's much easier to make a case for the back-end work that needs to be done.

Comment: *"<-insert rant about non-tech people telling tech people what to do here->"*, management should 100% percent be telling tech people **what** to do, that is why they are management and responsible for the **business**, that is what they do best. What they 100% should **not** be doing is telling them **how** to do it, tech people should decide on **how** to **technically** achieve **what** they have been asked to do. Anything else is complete **naïveté**!

Comment: Demanding a full rewrite is naive but my hunch is that the engineers can't get bandwidth for fixing tech debt via incremental refactoring either. That's probably the fault of the technical manager since product can only propose product features and bug fixes.

Comment: But engineers DO control estimates. So just bake in some refactoring with each bug fix. Problem solved.

Comment: @Kevin - I definitely can't get behind "lie about your time on other items to make time for an item no one will let you work on otherwise". If you can't make a case for fixing the issue, then the issue needs to stay "broken" until it becomes a large enough problem to allow the "fix this broken code" to bubble to the top.

Comment: That said, I don't see a problem with saying "I had to fix this other line on this page, while I was in there I cleaned up these compiler warnings / fixed other obviously broken code / etc".

Comment: That's where I disagree. Firstly you arent lying. You're estimating the cost of ensuring the feature or fix is delivered at quality.

Comment: Sprint Retrospective? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)#Sprint_retrospective.5B15.5D

Comment: Oh Im sorry.. you are right I didn't mean what to do.. I meant more so in terms of doing a complete rewrite that we understand what to do becuse the application already exists..  I guess I really meant to just say I wish they were more informed technically so they understood how bad things are under the covers.. That is why I prefer technical managers.. They can understand this quicker

Comment: Politically speaking, you do want to avoid the words "total rewrite" at all costs. To non-tech-oriented managers it often mistranslates to "total long-term failure I'll get the blame for." I do agree that the temptation to rip stuff out and completely replace it is an instinct we should be wary of, but if something is such a tangled mess you can't even wrap the soup up in a series of adapter objects to make sense of it and consistently handle contingencies that people keep bumping into in every problem they tackle, it's time to grab an axe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is so hard for people. His business case is right here:

```
We seem in an endless loop of just patching old code with 'Stories'.
```

Developer time is money. Lots of money. I left a company that planned on revamping their UI over a year ago and hoped that adopting scrum would help them stop spinning their wheels. What happened? Same ol' same ol'. They continued to bolt new features on and "technical debt" had no business case even though half the code we wrote became meaningless with every iteration due to the underlying codebase being a complete outdated mess. Not one thing has changed on their front end since I left, and I was brought on for the very purpose of completely revamping it. In the two months I was there I didn't actually touch a lick of CSS or JavaScript. I was just messing with HTML and some ancient Java templating system from the late 1990s.

My answer? Do what you can, but if the other developers have already given up and are working late to meet sprint goals rather than assert more practical deadlines and insisting that tech debt is in fact a blocking issue, assume the worst and start looking for a new job now. Your developers are either unable or not allowed to communicate their concerns or business is too !@#$ing shortsighted to understand how much money they're pissing away.

Ignoring these problems ALWAYS costs more in the long run. And not a little bit more, but a LOT more. Not only is it a sucking chest wound where development time is concerned, but it's also inevitably going to reduce your talent levels as developers who know better and have other options will avoid your company like the plague. My current boss is a developer AND the owner of the company. There's stuff we won't rewrite in favor of focusing on other priorities, but when something truly needs a refactor due to being a consistent timesink, it gets a proper refactor. And the results are obvious. Modifying and adding new stuff becomes easier and faster by multiple factors. What once may have taken hours can take minutes with proper architecture. Business doesn't like to hear it, but it's worth putting things on hold for that.

Scrum is a failure in environments where developers don't hold a lot of sway, IMO, because it's too easy for the business types to want to ignore maintenance and updates in favor of bullet points they can put on their "successful initiatives" lists when evaluation time comes around. They will always favor their hides and potential for promotion in favor of the long-term, even when it consistently bites them in the ass to ignore these issues too.

Scrum is also a profit-motivated industry and then some. Companies pay a lot of money for scrum training. People looking to adopt should cast a wary eye towards who is being marketed to and how realistic it's really going to be within their given culture.

Regardless, if you actually give a damn about development, a crappy codebase, management with wax in its ears and developers without spines is a recipe for misery and an environment that will do very little to enhance your skillset in any useful regard. Don't hesitate to start putting steps in motion to [GTFO](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GTFO) before you've actually discovered whether your efforts to fix the problem are actually paying off.

Comment: As regards refactoring, I find it odd that people can't 'internalise' that refactoring is a constant part of all development, not something you have a bash at when the problem is so bad there's not much you can do.

Comment: You'll get no disagreement from me on the boyscout rule. I patch up bits of my code all the time when touching on it for other purposes. When you fear doing so will introduce more bugs than improvement, you have an architecture problem or you just don't know what you're looking at.

Comment: Or you don't have unit tests. :)  One of the main benefits of unit-testing is that it allows you to refactor with confidence.  The biggest problem with good practice is the same as everything- it requires discipline and generally people prefer to be lazy.

Comment: That or they're yet another gift from the extreme coding crowd that can just as easily be turned into a tool that enables bad behavior in the wrong hands. Automated tests are useful at key points but I prefer sound architecture and writing to an interface rather than a test.

Comment: I would say that's the same for anything, personally I write the tests to help define the interface.

Comment: Refactoring may have been possible 8 years ago. A rewrite is coming. It is just a matter of time and I look forward to do.. since as a coder the rewrite is the fun part!

Comment: Then comes the pain of all the kludges to be put back in as there are those little exceptions that may not easily be caught by the initial analysis.

Comment: I'm primarily a JS developer so it's possible I just don't run into the sorts of legacy systems and database problems or larger multi-dev efforts a lot of app devs have to deal with but I do handle significant complexity and these project-slaying hard-to-diagnose bugs people worry about generally haven't been a huge problem for me. Coding with a preference for loose coupling and the DRY principle alone, however you achieve those things, goes a long way, IMO. I try to keep an open mind but TDD strikes me as treating the symptom rather than the disease, at least within my specialty.

Answer (score 32):

If you would really be doing Scrum, which I doubt, the Product Owner would be responsible for deciding about a rewrite. Most of the times a rewrite is not a good idea, btw, because it produces no new functionality, only introduces new bugs.

http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/01/09/the-big-redesign-in-the-sky
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

To expand on "rewrite is not a good idea":

It is almost always better to try a gradual improvement. Like Jarrod Robertson wrote in a comment, find a module that needs improvement become the expert for that module and write a story for the next sprint for improving that particular module. Explain to the product owner why that module needs work.

Comment: If only you saw what a mess this Hybrid Classic ASP/.NET 1.1 apps have come to be. Production has been breaking recently and no one even knows what the fix it.. The guy who wrote that piece is long gone.

Comment: The guess I need to take the project owner aside and tell her to stop writing stories and understand how bad things are.. But people are comfortable here.. They enjoy just things moving along as they always have.. Change is risky for the higher ups so there is no incentive

Comment: If you have as much experience and wisdom as you claim, **step up** and be the guy that figures out that failing module, become the expert on it and fix it, and then put together a business case to re-write it, because then you will be the **expert** on that module.

Comment: Some messes need to be cleaned up. Quoting Joel articles and asserting that rewrites rarely pan out without any statistics which would be dubious anyway (because who brags about successful rewrites?) does not change that.

Comment: @ErikReppen So when your living room is messy you tear down the house and build a new one?

Comment: If you read his comments he's not talking about the living room. It's probably difficult to tell where one room begins and another ends. And the whole house is on fire.

Comment: @ErikReppen: We've just finished a successful rewite! About 20% of the size, 5x faster and a lot nicer API to boot. Just putting in a data-point there.

Comment: @punkouter - if "Production has been breaking recently", then you should be able to write a story that states "as a user, I want X to work" and the tasks for the story will include "fix the broken module".

Comment: I've definately seen systems so poorly put together that incremental change is 10x harder and takes 10x longer than a rewrite.

Comment: Whoa there, cowboy. Before we just make a blanket statement about "rewrite is not a good idea", I think we need to qualify that with the truth that moving to new technologies and adapting to the times is essential for the IT-survival of your business. If you don't adopt newer (hopefully better) technologies and the advantages they give, your competitors will. This is true of tech in general. The Model-T was a perfectly good vehicle, but thanks to competition and the adoption of new technology, cars have been "re-written" many times over into the much better vehicles we drive today.

Comment: This "improve a particular **module**" is all well and good assuming that that can be done.  Very often, systems like the one the OP is working on are [big balls of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) and are a mess of spaghetti-code and interwoven dependencies. "Changing one thing" becomes impossible without risking bugs in seemingly unrelated areas, and refactoring to introduce unit tests is also impossible due to tight coupling and lack of separation of concerns.  In these, unfortunately all too common cases, a complete re-write **is** the best, and indeed, only solution.

Comment: @blesh he didn't make a blanket statement. He qualified it by saying "most of the times"...

Comment: + for "rewriting can be bad"  Case in point: Netscape went from market domination to dead because in part of a rewrite gone wrong (they lost their market leadership).

Comment: @blesh Migrating to a new platform/technology is a topic of its own (BTDT)...

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a new platform/technology. It could simply be a new methodology. For example, to get solid unit testing in an application, it could require a rewrite or some serious refactoring. Something could be written in new technologies with legacy methodology, and it might be worthwhile to migrate to the current state of "best practice" to better leverage the advantages of both the newer technology and the patterns and practices themselves.

Answer (score 18):

I'm going to be really blunt...

- Are you in charge of the developers in this job?
- Are you the project leader?
- How much "stake" do the developers hold in the project?
- What is your business justification for a rewrite?
- What is it about the code base that makes it entirely useless and unrecoverable?

You've stated that you have just started a job, and yet you already appear to be a master of the situation there. Perhaps I have misunderstood the intent of your question, but I get the impression that you've entered a job where you see a number of problems, and you have jumped to the easiest conclusion in which the code is broken and the only way forward is a rewrite, but have you really considered the cost to your employer to do so?

With any existing code base - no matter how poor a state it is in - the owner will usually have a sizable investment in the product(s) the code represents.  There are both direct and indirect costs associated with the code base, and a rewrite is often the very last thing you want to do as a software developer, as you risk devaluing your code assets, and thus getting a lower return on all of your prior efforts.

Take the Window's operating system as an example. With each new version created, there has been a big chunk of code carried forward from the previous version.  Sometimes, entire libraries and APIs are dragged forward across several generations of OS.  Why?  Because the developers know that these elements work, have been tested, have been patched and fixed to prevent security and memory problems, and because they have cost a hell of a lot of money to get into that state. Nobody wants to throw away working code when it is making them money, even if the maintenance costs are relatively high, the cost to start from scratch will always be higher still, and in a company like Microsoft's case, they have billions in the bank which allow them to start from the beginning if they want to, but they don't because they want to maximize their return from their investment. Your employer is no different to Microsoft, except for the bit about having billions in cash to throw at a project.

So the code is a mess, and it sounds like there are communication and boundary issues between the various areas of the company.  What can you or your colleagues do about this?

One option is to simply continue on as the team has been, and hope for a miracle in the future. Probably not a good idea, and likely to only increase your frustration and stress.

A better option is to simply knuckle down and do your jobs, but as a part of this look for opportunities to add tests to support those areas of code that appear to be the most fragile, then refactor them until they become more stable.  You'll have an easier time making a compelling argument to improve the company's investment instead of arguing to simply throw it all away.

An even better option is to be organised as a team, and to ensure you get someone on side with enough seniority that they can make a good case to allow the team more flexibility to schedule time to improve the code base.  I don't care how busy a company is, or how rigid the schedule appears to be, there are always the occasional "lulls" in activity that can be used to squeeze in an improvement or two.  It's even better however if the improvements can be made while completing other tasks. If it were me, I'd be cozying up to a manager and introducing them to concepts in some of the canonical books that software developers read.  [Clean Code](http://www.bookdepository.com/Clean-Code-Robert-Martin/9780132350884) is probably the one your team needs the most. Plant a few seeds about how to improve the code, and provide a few examples of what you mean. A good manager will see the value of adding incremental improvements to code, especially if you are able to describe the concept of [Technical Debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt). Help your team leader or manager to make a good business case for improving code, and they'll have a better motivation to act on it.

It's also not enough to say "the code is untidy". You need to encourage your colleagues to practice coding clean all of the time, and to use clean coding technique to encourage a little tidying up as you go. I have a little poster that I print out and hang from my office wall every time I take on a new job.  It says "Always strive to leave the code a little more beautiful than you found it". Right next to it I add another which says "Lilies don't need to be gilded". They both serve to remind me that I should always try to improve what I find, but avoid simply gold-plating one problem with another.  Massive rewrites are often the worst sort of "gold-plating", because they are often done for the wrong reasons. Sure an entirely new product version might be justifiable at some point, but rarely simply because the code base is a mess.

Comment: No. I am not in charge. I am a dev that has coded 12 years professionally and 7 years .NET. I have been around on many contracts and after awhile you quickly can get a feel for the quality of code . How much 'Stake'?  I am not sure what you mean by that. We can keep plugging away fixing the old CLASSIC ASP that is now extremely fragile and take 10x longer to do than if these changes were part of a good modern arcitecture. The business justification is that the site is now crashing in production due to a module that no one seems to understand because of the high turnover

Comment: I don't think you understand just how bad this code base is. On top of that, this is not rocket scienece. This is CRUD 101. This is displaying a form , letting a user fill it out, validate and then create some reports and PDFs from the data. That is basically it.. But over 10 years the code has been fragmented into so many peices its awful. Ive been part of about 20 projects the past 12 years and this has got to be the worst collection of code I have seen that is actually used in production... I wish I can show you all

Comment: What I am doing for starters is finding the people who are on the team who have some passion for coding and are interested in being part of finally getting this right. It is not easy to find those people because of... http://brucefwebster.com/2008/04/11/the-wetware-crisis-the-dead-sea-effect/

Comment: I think the main problem over the past 10 years comes down to 'programmers' who figured out how to do the bare minimum to get something working and did that without any interest if doing things right.. Its is the difference between a guy who codes as a hobby and a guy who codes only to make money.

Comment: @punkouter: I don't think you understand the point being made here; The codebase being "bad" is not a business case for a rewrite. Having passion for coding and wanting to get things right is not a business case for a rewrite. Costly production bugs and outages, and taking months to implement trivial but important new features - THOSE provide a business case for a rewrite.

Comment: @punkouter I thought I might risk hitting a nerve with my opening comments. I meant this not as a criticism of you personally, but more because I know what it's like to work in a moribund environment where hires are bought cheap rather than for their skill, so the pressure to perform well  can make it very tempting to simply chuck the lot in and start again. The question is whether it is in the best interests of the business to do so, or would it be better to try and decode what the failing module does to reclaim that lost knowledge, which you might need to do so anyway during a rewrite.

Comment: @punkouter Your link to a description of the "Dead Sea" phenomenon is also particularly apt. It is of no value to the business to lose knowledge through attrition, and of great value to reclaim what it can.  An investment of your time to avoid a potentially expensive and unnecessary rewrite has greater business value than losing knowledge and expertise. Encouraging better hiring practices, and rising to the challenge of chipping away at the problem and improving the system is an opportunity for you to earn a little kudos and become a valued asset to your employer.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but while there certainly is some truth in what you say about Microsoft reusing code because it saves them money. That was not the main reason. The main reason was to remain backwards compatible and have happy customers. In fact, they spent hundreds of millions of dollars (if not more) keeping their new operating systems backwards compatible, even to the point of putting special checks in the OS code to see if a particular program was making a particular call that they knew was problematic. It wasn't until Vista that someone decided the cost wasn't worth it.

Comment: @dunk not every decision was to remain backwards compatible. Many elements were reused simply because they worked, and there was no need to reinvent the wheel on a whim.  Even so I don't feel this invalidates the point I was trying to make.  Your nitpicking is however appreciated. :-)

Comment: @Robins-point taken and I did give credit to your point being partially valid. I just remembered reading an article way back at how it was considered of utmost importance by Microsoft management that their new OS's be backwards compatible, no matter the cost. It was the reason for quite a few of the late delivery dates. I thought that would be interesting info for people to know, but your point was valid, just wish you chose a different example.

Comment: "Ive been part of about 20 projects the past 12 years" - no wonder you don't have any tolerance for dealing with old code. You up and leave as soon as the greenfield project is done with. The majority of software development involves working on old "bad" code. A rewrite will not solve anything. You have to do the hard stuff to make software better: write unit tests, refactor old modules, document business logic, etc.

Comment: The link was kind of off topic but the bigger picture is really about having developers that would not allow the code base to become what it has. While the rewrite will take time.. The length is takes to make small changes also takes alot more time than it would after a rewrite so after awhile the rewrite would pay for itself anyways

Answer (score 13):

Here is the official definition of the **Scrum Development Team** from the official [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrum.org/storage/scrumguides/Scrum_Guide.pdf). I put emphasis on the parts that concerns you directly:

> The Development Team consists of professionals who do the work of delivering a potentially  releasable Increment of “Done” product at the end of each Sprint. Only members of the  Development Team create the Increment. Development Teams are structured and empowered by the organization to organize and **manage their own work**. The resulting synergy optimizes the Development Team’s overall efficiency and effectiveness. Development Teams have the following characteristics:
>
> - **They are self-organizing. No one (not even the Scrum Master) tells the Development Team how to turn Product Backlog into Increments of potentially releasable functionality;**
> - Development Teams are cross-functional, with all of the skills as a team necessary to create a product Increment;
> - Scrum recognizes no titles for Development Team members other than Developer,
>     regardless of the work being performed by the person; there are no exceptions to this rule;
> - Individual Development Team members may have specialized skills and areas of focus, but accountability belongs to the Development Team as a whole; and,
> - Development Teams do not contain sub-teams dedicated to particular domains like testing 
>     or business analysis.

The Development Team is therefore **responsible of its own mess** and should address it itself, without having to ask anyone outside the team.

Include a technical debt fixing time in each of your future estimation, and ensure that the quality of the software you deliver is top notch.

If you really have to do a complete rewrite, you must address the problem at the Scrum Restrospective. Product Owner may eventually cancel the project and start a new one. Product Owner is also the only one able to cancel a sprint.

Comment: The team is responsible for their own mess, but they don't get to choose the priority of technical debt versus new features. It is the product owner who decides that. It's just that, once the PO has decided on the priority of the backlog, the team can decide how to deliver it. They can say "we can't deliver feature X without first refactoring Y" but they can't say "no, sorry, we won't add any new features until we rewrite it from scratch".

Comment: @BryanOakley: Rewriting from scratch is not what I suggest. I suggest to reduce the technical debt progressively as the development team work on the concerned areas. And I also suggest that they estimate accordingly.

Comment: That sousd good but what if we need new servers, new databases, new software in order for us devs to have all the tools we need to do the rewrite ? ANd how does the rewrite begin when the only 'Stories' are about fixing current problems and never about the concept of allowing a rewrite ?

Comment: The reason ofr the mess is the constant turnover and people writing one off web apps that get loosely tied together by some Oracle web services that pass around authentication/authorization/roles in a session object. So there is no way to edit the 10 random web apps to make things better..it needs to be completely re thought.. But getting that across to non tech people seems hard

Comment: @punkouter: if you have to rewrite, address the problem at the scrum retrospective. Then the Product Owner will take the responsability to cancel the current project and start a new one.

Comment: Don't assume that the decision to rewrite is the 'right' one just because it's the one that appeals to the devs most. Sometimes there is a good business reason to deliver features now, even though it's going to increase technical debt.

Comment: @DJ The problem is that all too often, that is always the business case and not just "sometimes." Scrum is designed to shove tech debt under the carpet and does nothing to seriously address the problem of devs continuing to have intermediaries between them and the business concerns.

Comment: @EP You said it. There is a under current of code that has gotten worse and worse to a point now of being extrmely difficult to maintain. SCRUM is to general of a process to talk about dealiing with this specifically. And if the product owner does not understand the urgency then its just going to continue to get more and more inefficient to the point now where we are crawling and taking days to get simple functionality done.... but then again. maybe no one cares how long it takes ? No one here gets paid anymore or less depending on how long pieces of functionality take (its gov tpye work)

Answer (score 8):

As **you** describe this, I have to say I don't see anything that has anything to do with SCRUM, or your product development team being a problem **currently**.

**This is Normal**

What you describe is the **normal** entropy of a code base. In your case, the team probably started off farther off from ideal, but still every code base eventually becomes a [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/).

In a completely **perfect** [greenfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project) scenario, all you can possibly do is start farther from absolute entropy and move towards it slower.

I agree with others, the code base mess is because of developers. I am sure it predates the adoption of SCRUM by many years.

**This isn't a technical or developer decision to re-write, it is a business decision.**

You aren't privy to why the product owners don't want a re-write. You as a developer think it is needed, but is there really any **business case** for it?

If there is a true **business case**, not just a hand waving; *"the code is a legacy mess I want to start greenfield because that is what I want"*, then management would entertain the expense of a re-write, given a consideration of a return on that investment.

You haven't given one solid **business case** for a re-write, just a **rant** about your **opinion** on how everyone else caused this mess and **you** don't want to deal with it.

**Proof - Profit drives business decisions to toss out working software, not some [OCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) need for a clean code base**

If you can really show **proof**, not just theory but hard **proof** that spending `X` dollars on a greenfield re-write will be **guaranteed to MAKE** `X * N` dollars for the business in `Y` time frame ( where `N` is high and `Y` is short ), you might get some traction from management. This is a highly unlikely case that you can present and prove.

Otherwise you just need to deal with it, this is reality. Contrary to your adamant assertions that there is absolutely no way forward without this grand immaculate re-write, I would bet money that 5+ years from now code base you are complaining about will still be working and running somewhere providing someone functionality and value long after you have left the company.

Comment: Messy code bases are very frequently a direct result of management. 200 outsourced Java devs on the same back end with no version control because the higher-ups "don't see the need for it," for instance.

Comment: that doesn't mean it isn't the responsibility for the developers to use some version control system *internally* regardless, I would say it is still the developers responsibility to take care of themselves and their best interests regardless. In your straw man, those 200 devs didn't do what they needed to do, management didn't put a gun to their head and forbid them to set up version control system themselves.

Comment: Messy Code bases are never a direct result of management since management is never directly responsible for writing code. Its that simple. Manangement is responsible for having and fostering a less than ideal working environment for the developers, but the responsibility to work through problems such as a lack of version control always falls on those doing the actual work.

Comment: Outsourced devs is a management problem. People on the inside knew better. Management liked to pretend they were saving buttloads of money by hiring 200 devs when they in fact probably could have done great with 20 competent ones. Much like a lot of Scrum implementations I've seen, the adopted strategy was the product of incompetence and nothing the devs that were actually company employees had any control over.

Comment: @Goblyn, when management sets unreasonable delivery goals and encourages a culture of horrendously bad quantity-of-features-oriented design with 800 cooks in every kitchen resulting in a constant rejiggering of UI features as everybody strives to prove that they have valuable input to bring to a website they shouldn't by definition of their actual job responsibilitie have any involvement in and and then they set deadlines without actually talking to developers, and never give you time to clean up the mess, bad codebases happen and I don't think that's on the devs.

Comment: @Erik, not saying managers dont have to take responsibility for a bad code base (or any other bad decisions made in their department) and that managers arent directly responsible for providing the environment in which the developer work, such as the scenario you described. But the only person who can be directly responsible for the code base is the person writing the code itself.

Comment: That's like saying the company fire marshall is responsible for keeping the building from burning down when his bosses insist it's okay for employees to continue having their asbestos suit blowtorch fights near the place where all the propane tanks are kept in the warehouse. I think not.

Comment: I would also like to add that it is stupid to not make your devs privy to business goals. I've never understood why people are so intent on hiding this stuff from the people actually determining the behavior of their product. Knowing a company's long-term goals can in fact inform how you architect an app. Also, devs, good ones at least, solve problems. Constantly, they solve problems. Some of us anticipate and solve them ahead of time in our heads or at least leave the right doors open in our code.

Comment: I think whoever does the hiring is the first person to blame. If you hire the right people that take pride in creating well arcitected code then the developers can police themselves moving forward... Here the problem is turnover and not having someone.. wether thats a manager or lead dev to oversee what individuals are doing

Comment: I always take it as a bad sign when none of the active devs are involved in an interview process. HR/Hiring managers should insist and devs who know what they're doing and think beyond the short term should want to be involved.

Answer (score 7):

I'm usually skeptical when people push for "big rewrites". There are some cases where it definitely makes sense but most of the time, that legacy code has value (in that it's already in production and being used for the purposes that inspired its creation). Performing a big rewrite is in many cases the opposite of agile. How long would it take to bring the new version of the application to a point where it can viably replace the existing application.

The approach I'd prefer is what Martin Fowler calls the [strangling vine](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerApplication.html). Implement new functionality (including changes to existing functionality) using the new approach but use the existing application as a trellis which the new functionality can grow upon. This gives you the best of both worlds, you don't have to stop everything while the big rewrite is being brought up to snuff, but you get the benefit of writing new code that takes advantage of updated frameworks. It's definitely a more difficult approach than starting clean and might not be as sexy, but it provides more value to the business than dumping everything that's there because it's outdated.

Comment: That can be difficult if the existing base is enough of a mess. He's talking about multiple legacy asp.net systems by completely different authors tightly coupled together for the same damn site. Web forms alone is a monster and I'm sure that's in the mix.

Comment: Oh I never said it would be the easiest route...but it's more palatable to stakeholders. Also, going through it once, hopefully you'll make sure that when today's latest and greatest becomes tomorrow's outdated, it's easier to phase it out.

Comment: I agree. But like Ive said (and not sure everyone heres) .What exissts now is a collection of about 9 seperate web applications half being Classic ASP and the other half being differnt forms of ASP.NEt. All using totally differnt ways to handle data access etc.. So the only way to do what is talked about is to fake the UI to look like the new code is part of the old code.. so yeah maybe.. but then theres a the database.. One table has 400 fields!

Comment: I'm curious. What does that table represent? That's the worst thing I've heard of since I saw i++; doSomething(i); repeated over a dozen times in some code that spilled out of a busted JSP tag.

Answer (score 5):

Where I am and how we work this is what we would do:
Write a new story and hand it to the product owner, who will then decide how to prioritise it.
An example would be:
"As a Developer of Product X, I would like to re-write the code in this area so that future development is more efficient"
Acceptance criteria would then need to be along the lines of:
Re writing / refactoring x so that it is better in this way.

I don't know about the situation where you are but here if we wanted to re-start from scratch it would be a case of sitting down with the product owner and persuading them why and then writing a pile of stories to re-create existing functionality.

The other things we've done to try and deal with bad and / or legacy code have been to include tasks for reworking when tasking out the user stories.

Comment: So the devs can write 'stories' and submit them ?   The problem is explaining the reasons for re writing is too technical for them to handle... All I can say is .. 'The current code is hard to manage and breaks'..

Comment: @punkouter: if the reasons for wanting to rewrite are purely technical (i.e. not costing the business money) then you HAVE NO sufficient reason for a rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Are you saying that any technical reasons are never sufficient for rewriting something?  That's a fundamentally broken approach, if I understand you correctly.  One thing that continually gets on my nerves is the normal master/slave approach that the 'business' determines everything that 'IT', or any department does.  That is only true to a certain extent.  IT has its own requirements that are internal and are not decided by the business- this is one thing that is usually missing and leads to non-engineered, not fit-for-purpose software.

Comment: As a developer I would like to make changes in approximately 1/10th to 1/100th of the typical time it takes now, and as a business owner, I would like to stop hemorrhaging money by trying to ram square "value add" pegs through a hole that's shaped more like broken technology on the verge of collapse.

Comment: I let ANYONE write backlog items.  I like backlog items such as "turn this business application into a video game".  Product owners will set the priority accordingly.  This answer is great.  Do not over look "I would like to re-write the code in this area".  THIS AREA != entire application rewrite.  Brownfield development is a fact of life and developers who can succeed here will go far.

Comment: @user12355 As I have seen, Michaels point is that if it isn't losing them money, it won't make them money, then there isn't ever a case. If they aren't losing money a rewrite costs them money. Money that can't be recovered. A developer could make the case of "this code sucks" but unless they can prove a financial benefit to their employer they will never get the green light to rewrite unless they do it on their own.

Comment: @user12355: Technical reasons are definitely sufficient for a user story. They're not necessarily sufficient to get that story promoted to the top of the list and placed into a sprint.

Comment: @user, but that logic ignores all the development time wasted implementing new features in a system that forces you take take 10 steps forward, 9 steps back.

Comment: @user12355: IT is a *part* of the business, it doesn't exist for its own sake. That has nothing to do with a "master/slave approach". IT requirements are valid and important if they have an impact on the business goals. Dismissing them because they don't correspond directly to revenue is bad, but so are ivory tower approaches.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Any part of the business is _part_ of the business. My experience is that IT does not live in an ivory tower, but tries to balance practical needs with medium-term requirements that software is designed and maintainable. The 'business', whatever that is, lives in some alternative position to an 'ivory tower', where they just push ahead with ill-thought out plans without considering the impact on the rest of the business or discussing what they need from any other part and then turn up saying 'oh, we've promised to deliver this entire new system in a month, can you do that?'.

Comment: Its a non profit so there is no money being lost.. Maybe thats part of the bigger problem (lack of incentive). The current code has already crashed many times in production.. But if no one is losing money then people are not as bothered by that.

Answer (score 4):

Deciding on big rewrites is a business decision. You can try to influence business decisions by selling in your point of view to the people responsible for the business part of things.

However; the change in code quality from one iteration to the next is a developer decision.
If you allow the code quality to decline, you are adding technical debt in order to fulfill the product owner's expectations now.
What you can do is to start taking responsibility for the code you write and make sure it improves the code base, not the other way around. Now this means you will lose velocity, since you are continuously decreasing the amount of technical debt, and your product owner will surely be dissapointed. You can try to explain that in your eagerness to please, you've let the code quality degrade and you're now taking steps to correct this issue.

Now, I realize that it's a terrifying step to take, and it might feel tempting to delay it just one more sprint so you can get out feature X before an important deadline.
Unfortunately, it will just get more difficult the longer you wait.

By the way, this is not strictly a Scrum issue, nor am I suggesting a solution that is specific to Scrum. This is about developers taking ownership of the code.

Comment: Right and when you have a history of 10 years of constant turnover and one-offs by devs who clearly could not code well or understand modern arcitecture then.. you have what I have now... I am alarmed more than anyone else since I am new to the job and not use to seeing such a low quality level of code..  I want the rewrite not just for my selfish desire of enjoying writing new good code.. but for the sake of everyone else as well .. even if they do not understand the situation as I do.

Comment: I can only reiterate what's already been said; Formally, you can't decide that now is the time for the big rewrite. I guess you could try to show stakeholders how much effort it takes to incrementally turn your codebase into a slightly less painful state, and compare it to the effort it takes to do a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

The developers are responsible for alerting the world on the code base's current state. This can happen during a daily scrum, a retrospective or just informally. It may seem obvious but if you don't express clearly what a mess it is and how much time you waste because of it, no one will ever notice. The Scrum Master will typically be responsible for passing the information on to the PO and the people in charge of the project and persuading them something needs to be done, and then facilitating the implementation of a solution by the team.

As a side note, a big bang rewrite is IMO not necessarily the right answer to this kind of problem. However fed up the devs are with the current code base, taking small measurable steps towards a cleaner architecture is often a better idea since you can see the progress, justify your work by regularly showing the PO the accomplishments and continue the flow of implementing new user stories in parallel as opposed to getting lost in an endless, resource-monopolizing makeover.

Comment: As I mentioned.. There is no way forward with a collection of 6 Classic ASP sites  + 4 .net 1.1 sites that are all combined into one site. All coded by different people in different ways.

Comment: I am pretty sure that code base will move forward, for years to come, to paraphrase [Dr. Ian Malcom from Jurrasic Park "I'm, I'm simply saying that management, uh... finds a way"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/quotes?qt=qt0463040).

Comment: It might be around in years to come but varying flavors of legacy .net sites tightly coupled together is not likely to move very far in those years.

Comment: Sure, but if all those .net sites continue to function, and their functioning continues to generate revenue either directly or indirectly for the company, why is forward momentum so important? When the revenue is directly impacted by the quality of the codebase, you can believe that the managers will waste no time in redesigning it as they all have mortgages to pay just like the developers do.

Comment: Ceaseless forward momentum is generally the root of the problem in the first place in my experience. The pain starts when turnaround expectations don't diminish while they still turn a deaf ear to the problems in the architecture and think Scrum is going to magically develop new sets of complete features every two weeks without further exacerbating the problem. I'm not saying we shouldn't be wary of the urge to rip stuff out if we can't come up with alternatives that solve the time sinks we're encountering, but I've seen at least two very good cases for major overhauls in my career.

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> Where is the part in Scrum where the developers can have the power to say that enough is enough and demand that they are given time to start the big rewrite? We seem in an endless loop of just patching old code with 'Stories'. So things are being run by the non-technical people who seem to have no desire to push for a rewrite because they don't understand how bad the code base has gotten..

As someone who is both a manager and a developer, the simplest answer to your question is there is no part in Scrum, or any other methodology, or in any business scenario, where the developer have the power to say enough is enough and demand a re-write. Many people here have made good, valid, arguments to explain why re-writes are frequently bad ideas, and to explain how change can and should be brought about in an incremental, agile fashion. And I agree with them all.

But the bottom line is even simpler. You don't get to make that decision, EVER. You are the employee, and the only decision you really get to make is "will I continue to work for these asshats or find a new job that fears my mad skillz." Your new job won't allow you to make that decision either, but at least you will feel like you are in control of your fate as you hop from job to job.

Comment: If I'm reading between the lines here correctly, it sounds like you're a bit bitter about your inability to hold on to new-hires. If I'm not wrong, have you considered that the new-hires whose skills are in fact in enough demand for them to walk when they don't like working at your company are the only non-constants in the equation?

Comment: Not even close. Actually the employees in my department have been with me for a few years now. I have virtually no turn over. The point I am trying to make is that ultimately, in any company, in any industry, what work the employee performs is completely up to the person signing the paycheck and not the employee. The only decision the employee has to make, myself included when my boss makes a request, is to persist or not persist with the employee relationship. The original poster asked when does he, as an employee, get to dictate development. The answer is never.

Comment: Then what was with the "fear my mad skilz" characterization? This guy is an experienced dev. And I can tell you from  my experience with similar situations that the problem he's talking about is not just a matter of wanting things his way but actually an on-going disaster that is both making everybody miserable and costing his employer a lot more in wasted dev time and talent retention than they probably realize.

Comment: Because I was illustrating the fallacy of the basic argument, which was rooted in ego (in a psychological sense.) Its not a question of how skilled he is. Its not a question of how messed up the code is. Its not a question of what the development methodology can do for him. It is a question about power. The power to make decisions in an employee relationship resides with the employer. The only deciding power an employee has is to cancel the relationship when it becomes too much to bear.

Comment: Right but he's talking about the scrum process not the employer/employee relationship. I personally believe Scrum is lousy at handling tech debt issues. In fact I never heard the term tech debt until Scrum. Code requires cleanup and maintenance. Ignoring that in favor of a constant stream of visible value add features is a costly mistake.

Comment: I agree, scrum is lousy for dealing with tech debt. But I disagree about the basis of the original question. He was in fact asking a employer / employee relationship question, but just mentioned scrum in the question. Its like if I asked, "As a Christian, whats the best way to make an Enchillada?". Its not really a theological question; its a question about cooking even if I made the mistake of thinking my religious preferences were relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, but am not sure what it has to do with Scrum. The decision whether to re-write code does not depend on the development process.

Comment: A development process that promises things will get completed every two weeks can do a lot to stand in the way of needed large-scale refactoring that's been ignored for years. The first thing I noticed in scrum training is the way they sort of glaze over the topic of tech debt. It's not exciting to declare that your app is now leaner and meaner and you can do things faster. Business types want visible value adds they can show to friends and investors.

Answer (score 1):

Wait....what?

You're *patching*? You should be **refactoring**. Stick to agile values. Use TDD and appropriate practices and the situation will eventually become better.